# Why does VBA .Formula property give run time error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA for Excel 2017 on my iMac I have the following problem:

```
Sub UpdateSummary()
    Total = "=QUOTIENT(120;60)"
    Sheets("Summary").Range("H15").Formula = Total
End Sub
```

This gives run time error 1004

However if I do:

```
Sub UpdateSummary()
    Total = "QUOTIENT(120;60)"
    Sheets("Summary").Range("H15").Formula = Total
End Sub
```

and add the = sign manually in the cell H15, the formula works as expected.

What can I do to solve this problem?

PS: The original code is more complex than above obviously, but this code snippet is generating the error and probably easier to understand than the original code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Total = "=QUOTIENT(120;60)"
```

should be

```
Total = "=QUOTIENT(120,60)"
```

when adding formula via VBA you should always use the comma list separator (unless you use `FormulaLocal` (where you can use your local list separator)

Comment: This is a very confusing feature of Microsoft Windows/Microsoft Office/Excel VBA regarding regional settings. I had exactly the same problem until I discovered this answer.The point is that in Windows regional settings you can set the regional list separator as, i.e. "," or ";". I have set semicolon (;), if I write manually in excel cell using comma (,) it gives me an error. However, if I fill the cell from VBA I have to use comma, as semicolon gives me run time error 1004. Illogical behavior!!!

Comment: It's not illogical - VBA purposely has both `Formula` and `FormulaLocal` properties.  The advantage of the way it's set up is you can write a formula to a cell using the US-style separator and it will *automatically* translate the formula to the user's locale settings (if those are different).  So you can write one set of VBA which works across locales.   If you really want to use a specific locale in your VBA then you can do that using `FormulaLocal`.  That might not be super-intuitive, but it's well-documented and useful.

Comment: OK, make sense but as you said, not intuitive at all!